# How to clear undo history in CodeMirror 6?

Tags: text, editor, codemirror, undo

`editor.clearHistory();` works in [CodeMirror 5](https://codemirror.net/5/) I believe, but what about [CodeMirror 6](https://codemirror.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
interface HistoryConfig {
    /**
    The minimum depth (amount of events) to store. Defaults to 100.
    */
    minDepth?: number;
    /**
    The maximum time (in milliseconds) that adjacent events can be
    apart and still be grouped together. Defaults to 500.
    */
    newGroupDelay?: number;
}
/**
Create a history extension with the given configuration.
*/
declare function history(config?: HistoryConfig): Extension;
```

```js
import { EditorView } from '@codemirror/view';
import { EditorState } from '@codemirror/state';
import { history } from '@codemirror/commands';

const state = EditorState.create({
  doc: 'my source code',
  extensions: [history({ minDepth: 10 })],
});

const view = new EditorView({
  parent: document.querySelector('#editor'),
  state,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The undo/redo functionality is implemented via an `Extension` called `history()`. Extensions can be added or removed 'at runtime', that is, during the lifetime of an `EditorView`, using a `Compartment`. As far as I understand, compartments are placeholders or boxes, that allow you to place or remove extensions after creation of the editor.
Using these compartments, we can add and remove the `history()` extension:

```js
import { history, historyKeymap } from '@codemirror/commands';

let undoRedo = new Compartment;
let editor = new EditorView({
    state: EditorState.create({
        extensions: [
            basicSetup,
            //...
            undoRedo.of([history()]),
            keymap.of([
                ...historyKeymap,
            ])
        ]
    }),
    parent: document.getElementById("txtInput")
});

function resetUndoRedo() {
    editor.dispatch({
        effects: undoRedo.reconfigure([]) //first remove history() to clear it!!
    });
    editor.dispatch({
        effects: undoRedo.reconfigure([history()])
    });
}

//a typical usage:
function setEditorText(text) {
    let transaction = editor.state.update({ changes: { 
                from: 0, 
                to: editor.state.doc.length, 
                insert: text} 
    });
    editor.update([transaction]);
    resetUndoRedo();
}
```